# not able to login using windows credentials using LDAP config - django

Tags: python, django, ldap

I am using trying to build a login page so that every user can login using their windows credentials. LDAP config of my organization is being used but not able to login from the windows credentials.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: i tried the settings.py with all the authentication of LDAP. it is showing no error but I am not able to login using my windows credentials.

Comment: i modified settings.py file and my views.py file. I am able to login now but I am not able to print the user details through ldap server. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [django-auth-ldap](http://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/)